# How do I unit test amcharts using jest with react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, amcharts

I have reproduced the compilation error that I came across while working on a project using Jest with amCharts. Apparently, Jest cannot compile anything to do with amchart for unit testing.

**Error**

```
/core.js:8
export { System, system } from "./.internal/core/System";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

  1 | import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
> 2 | import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
    | ^
  3 | import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";
  4 |
  5 | const data = [

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.tsx:2:1)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.067 s
Ran all test suites.

**Jest.config.ts**

```
module.exports = {
  roots: ["<rootDir>/src"],
  collectCoverageFrom: ["src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "!src/**/*.d.ts"],
  setupFiles: ["react-app-polyfill/jsdom"],
  testMatch: [
    "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  testRunner:
    "/home/xeonrazr/Playground/amcharts-jest-err/node_modules/jest-circus/runner.js",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/babelTransform.js",
    "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
    "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx|css|json)$)":
      "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$",
    "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$",
  ],
  modulePaths: [],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
    "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    "web.js",
    "js",
    "web.ts",
    "ts",
    "web.tsx",
    "tsx",
    "json",
    "web.jsx",
    "jsx",
    "node",
  ],
  watchPlugins: [
    "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
    "jest-watch-typeahead/testname",
  ],
  resetMocks: true,
};
```

**App.tsx**

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";

const data = [
  {
    country: "Lithuania",
    litres: 501.9,
  },
  {
    country: "Czech Republic",
    litres: 301.9,
  },
  {
    country: "Ireland",
    litres: 201.1,
  },
  {
    country: "Germany",
    litres: 165.8,
  },
  {
    country: "Australia",
    litres: 139.9,
  },
  {
    country: "Austria",
    litres: 128.3,
  },
  {
    country: "UK",
    litres: 99,
  },
  {
    country: "Belgium",
    litres: 60,
  },
  {
    country: "The Netherlands",
    litres: 50,
  },
];

function App() {
  const chartRef = useRef(am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart));

  useEffect(() => {
    let series = chartRef.current.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
    series.dataFields.value = "litres";
    series.dataFields.category = "country";
    chartRef.current.data = data;
    chartRef.current.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        data-testid="chartdiv"
        style={{ height: "600px", width: "100%" }}
        id="chartdiv"
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**App.test.tsx**

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";

test("renders learn react link", () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<App />);
  const chartEl = getByTestId("chartdiv");
  expect(chartEl).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

[Repo Link](https://github.com/XeonRazr/amcharts-jest-err.git)

Answer (score 0):

Jest currently doesn't understand either `import` or `export`. It looks like you followed common setup docs for your jest config so you're probably using babel and transpiling your code from using modules to using commonjs, but you're not transpiling your dependencies:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
  "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$", // <-- do not transform node_modules
  "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$",
],
```

But, what's causing your problem is that one of your exports (`amCharts`) needs to be transformed in order to make those `import`/`export` statements compliant with the commonjs format that jest is expecting.

Your easiest fix is probably to edit the `transformIgnorePatterns`:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
    //Add other modules here that ship ESM that Jest doesn't like
    'node_modules/(?!@amcharts)',
    "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$",
  ],
```

So we're saying "go ahead and don't transform anything in node modules unless it matches `@amcharts`. If you get more dependencies that need to be transformed, then you can add it to that regex.

For a different solution, if you like experimental features, then you can try turning on Jest's experimental support for esm: https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules.